# Recyclerview transparent background

Tags: android

How do I make my `Recyclerview` transparent. Not the items in it, but the actual component itself so I can see the view behind it. I tried this:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

But it doesn't work. If set it to a color (like red or blue) using that attribute it works though...

Comment: Use background color in parent layout of Recyclerview.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@null" />
```

with this, your `RecyclerView`'s background will be null and you can see the Parent View's background.

Comment: my recycler view contains  ConstraintLayout with a few TextView s. when I set android:background="@null" to the ConstraintLayout nothing happends and the default color stays the same. if i give it a color value instead it does change to the correct color.

Comment: in case anyone gets the same error I had, this answer solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50873866/9158986

Comment: @HilaGrossbard, your problem was not related with recyclerview's background, It was about the items inside. So your problem and it's solution is different eventually.