# Transparent Background For RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

this is my layout for a chat window in within my recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="418"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="100"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/btn_profilepic_recview_chats"
                                android:background="@drawable/ripple"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="323"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="100"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="323"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:src="@drawable/chat_img_bubbletop"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="#afebff">
                                <TextView
                                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:textSize="17sp"
                                    android:id="@+id/txt_chatmessage_recview_chats"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <ImageView
                                    android:src="@drawable/chat_img_bubbletop"
                                    android:rotation="180"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="100"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="323"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <TextView
                                android:text="12.02.2012"
                                android:id="@+id/txt_date_recview_chats"
                                android:textSize="12sp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="216"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The Background of the recyclerview is a simple image, that is supposed to show through the linear layouts. But unfortunately, this is the result:

[image]

So, as you can see, the background is displayed just right but the supposed to be transparent layout for the cardview i am using here is some wired black.

I can make it whatever color I want, but with:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

it just gets black.

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... turns out CARDVIEWS do not have such attribute. Making the rootlayout a linearlayout solved this issue.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: U know what, this would be a perfect solution :) thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change your CardView background color. you can use

```
app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Instead of

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

**Like :**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">

        <!-- Your view design -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```